# RegEx: найти всё, кроме года в конце строки

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Есть строка типа "любые буквы, пробелы и цифры, годы, но в конце стоит пробел и год из 4 цифр"
Мне для замены нужно выделить всё до года, включая последний пробел.

Например, из строки `текст 123 2024 текст 2012 text 1999` должно остаться только `1999`. Строки могут быть без года в конце (тогда результат - пустая строка). Перерыл все подобные темы, но не нашёл именно своего варианта. Пробовал что-то вроде `[^\d{4}]$`, но разумеется это не работает.

Подскажите, пожалуйста

Comment: Если у вас не работает ни один из примеров, поясните, что именно не работает. Добавьте дополнительную информацию в вопрос, не надо задавать новых вопросов.

Answer (score 1):

Регулярное выражение `[^\d{4}]$` находит любой символ, отличный от цифры, `{` и `}` в конце строки.

Найти любой символ, кроме четырёх цифр в конце строки (чтобы удалить, например), можно с помощью

```
(\d{4})$|.
```

Заменить нужно на `$1`, то есть текстом из первой захваченной подмаски.

- `(\d{4})$` - четыре цифры (`(\d{4})`, содержимое подмаски №1) в конце строки (`$`)
- `|` - или
- `.` - любой символ, кроме перехода на новую строку.

См. [пример работы выражения](https://regex101.com/r/vVtRJo/1)

**Другой вариант**

```
^(?:(?!\d{4}$).)+
```

См. [пример работы этого выражения](https://regex101.com/r/57iAya/1). Тут

- `^` - находит начало строки
- `(?:(?!\d{4}$).)+` - один и более повторов (как можно больше) любого символа, кроме перехода на новую строку, который не является начало подстроки, состоящей из четырёх цифр в конце строки.

Comment: Спасибо, буду разбираться. До того, как прочитал ваш ответ, перечитывал статью по теме и пришёл к такому варианту `.*\D{4}` Вроде работает, но только почему-то он не работает со строками типа `текст 2004 ее`

Comment: @user403267 `.*\D{4}` найдёт 0+ любых символов (кроме перехода на новую строку), как можно больше, до последнего вхождения 4 символов, отличных от цифр. Это явно не то, что вам надо.

Comment: Wiktor Stribiżew, ваши примеры рабочие, но конкретно в моём парсере они не работают. Мне создать новую тему или могу тут спросить? В общем, я думаю сделать две последовательные замены. 1-я - просто оставить 4 последних символа (независимо от того, год это или нет). 2-я - проверить на соответствие оставшихся символов году

Comment: @user403267 Добавьте подробности в **этот** вопрос. Объясните, что не работает.

Answer (score 0):

попробуйте воспользоваться такой конструкцией
`"\d{4}"\z`

Comment: Почему-то в программе не работает эта конструкция, работает \d{4}$ , но это выделение года в конце, а мне нужно выделить всё, кроме этого года

Comment: @user403267: Вы сами ещё раз свой вопрос перечитайте. `должно остаться только "1999"`

Comment: в задании всё верно написано, мне надо выделить регулярным выражением всё, кроме года в конце (если он есть в строке)

Answer (score 0):

Вроде бы захват групп везде работает - попробуйте `^(.+)(\d{4})$`, в первой группе `$1` будет текст, во второй `$2` - год.

Пример - https://regex101.com/r/abzkPw/3